# Download base64 Image in react native webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, expo, base64

I am writing a webview app in which i can download files from (html tag) urls to device. I can download files like png/jpg/pdf etc, but when url is a base64 string value i don't know how to download it. Can someone help me to achieve that?

For example, when the below html link clicked file abc.png can be downloaded easily

```
<a href="http://web.com/abc.png" download >Download</a>
```

But when url is base64 like below, webview can't download the "file":

````
<a href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." download>Download</a>```
````

Answer (score 0):

**EXPO SOLUTION:
 THIS IS NOT WORKING FOR ANDROID AND I DID NOT TEST FOR WEB**
**I'm still figuring out how to get the same result in Android, so if some knows how to do it plase answer this quesiton**
In iOS you can use onShouldStartLoadWithRequest event in your webVIew.
Just add your custom function to handle the image and make it available for sharing.
 Here's an example
webView

```
               <WebView
                        ref={webView}
                        domStorageEnabled = {true}
                        onLoad={onLoad}
                        useWebKit={true}
                        startInLoadingState={true}
                        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
                        javaScriptEnabled={true}
                        mixedContentMode={'always'}
                        onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest} // this is your event handler
                        allowFileAccess={true}
                        allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures={true}
                        cacheEnabled={false}
                        originWhitelist={["*"]}
                        source={{ uri: urlLoad }}
                        style={{  backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc',marginTop:20 }}

                    />
```

And the function used for handle the event

```
function onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(event) {
    const { url } = event;

        if(url.indexOf('data:image/png;base64,')>=0){

        
       downloadImage(url.split('data:image/png;base64,').pop(),'filename')
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

And the actual function that makes the logic

```
const downloadImage = async (base64String, filename) => {

    const downloadDir = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'images/';
    const imagePath = downloadDir + filename + '.png';
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(downloadDir, { intermediates: true });
    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(imagePath, base64String, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });

    await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(imagePath)
        .then(uri => {
            Sharing.shareAsync(uri);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
};
```